# Placing element in the top right corner in react native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, styles, stylesheet

The parent `component` has the following style

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I am placing another `component` within this component. I want it in the top-right corner.

Naturally, I would go with the following style in this child `component`:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    top: 20,
    right: 5,
  },
});
```

However, it places it in the top **left** corner. The only way I can move it into the right corner is replacing `right: 5` with `left: 500`. But thats kind of not the way to go...

Comment: what about using `alignSelf: 'flex-end'`

Comment: also remove css and stylesheet tag as it will not help or you will get css solution for this

Comment: @JigarShah removed. That helps. It moves it to the right. However, horizontally speaking its in the middle right now.

Comment: that is because you have `justifyContent: 'center',` . You can use `margin-top` to change horizontal position

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please check the below stylesheet for child component:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    marginTop: -5,
    position: 'absolute', // add if dont work with above
  }
});
```